# Non repeating pairs in Spark Data Frame

Tags: apache-spark

Consider DF1 data frame below.

DF1

```
a
b
c
d
```

I need at to be in the combination below

```
a,b
a,c
a,d
b,c
b,d
c,d
```

How do I achieve this is Spark. (Is it non - repeating cartesian product of self?)

Comment: If you can convert to an RDD: `res20.cartesian(res20).filter{case (a, b) => a.getString(0) < b.getString(0)}`, where instead of `<` you can plug a custom function that defines the ordering you want.

Comment: @axiom can you post it as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can convert to an RDD:

`rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter{case (a, b) => a.getString(0) < b.getString(0)}`, where instead of `<` you can plug a custom function that defines the ordering you want.